# Can I control the position of a console window on the screen?

Tags: virtual-console

I want my c/c++ program's console window to chose a specific position. is it possible either within the program or by system call?

Comment: If you use gtk you can specify a location and size for the window, but then it isn't a console application anymore.

Comment: It depends on what you want the program to do. I have only been tinkering with c and gtk for a short time and have a couple of simple programs completed.

Answer (score 0):

There are X server extensions that allow a program to specify where a window it creates should be drawn.  I don't remember these off the top of my head, but given that it's part of the X libraries (which are presumably used directly or indirectly if the program is creating windows) they should be easy enough to find?

If, on the other hand, this is a console application looking to change the position and/or size of the virtual console from which it is launched... my understanding is that there is no system for doing so.  It's possible to discover its dimensions and terminate with a message if it's too small, but actual direct control is not possible.  This is because a console application could well be run in a dumb text console without the X (GUI) server running at all.

All that said:  I think this question would possibly be more at home on Stack Overflow than on Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: I should perhaps add that there are other applications that could be called externally if an application can get sufficient knowledge of the window in which it's running.  `wmctl` is an external binary rather than a function to be called, but can manipulate arbitrary extant windows.